# Run on device from xcode after making archive

Tags: xcode

I have a project in Xcode 4.5.2. I was able to run the project to a device from Xcode until I built an ad-hoc version with the "archive" function. (After changing the code signing).

Now, when the device is plugged in I get the error "CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.0'".

I have checked which profiles are selected under "Code Signing" in build settings, trying both the generic "*" profile, and the profile I used to build the ad-hoc release (For both debug and release builds).

What confuses me is I can build the project and install it to the device through ITunes without issue. It seems it's now running the 'release' version and not the 'debug' version when building with a device connected now. The device is in the provision profile however, so shouldn't it work either way?

I've tried

- Restarting xcode,
- Deleting the derived data (From finder, not through the organizer),
- Deleting and reinstalling the provision profile.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which iOS version is running in your device? not iOS6.0 ?

Comment: I have one running IOS6 and one running IOS5.
I'm still able to build an archive file - install through iTunes - and it runs fine on both. The "Deployment Target" is set to 5.0

Comment: try development provisioning profile. I guess you used ad-hoc distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: I ended up just making a new project because of a deadline so never found out what setting got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your provisioning profile, make sure its a Distribution profile with your devices UDID on it.

I use a site called www.testflightapp.com, which will also help automate this process for you. Hope that helps